# Python: create interactive ssh-session with parameters host and user

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am trying to build a small tui-program that allows me to choose hostname and username for a ssh-session from a list.

My question is how to create an interactive ssh-session with these parameters.

I tried the subprocess.popen:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "username@host"], shell=True)
```

but it destroys my terminal-formating. There are line breaks all over the place and nothing is in line anymore. Also I cannot see what I'm typing that way.

My alternative idea is to open the ssh-session, exit the python program and attach to the ssh-session, but I don't know how to do it or if it is even possible.

Any help and ideas are appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "destroys my terminal-formatting"?  I have a Python script that does exactly this and it works just fine.

Comment: The lines are not starting on the left as usual but somewhere in the middle on the screen. As if every line break would add a few tab steps

Comment: @JadBlackstone I would add that in the question for clarity. Thanks!